# Replacing Cookie by Token based authentication in ASP.NET OWIN OpenIdConnect code authorization flow

Tags: asp.net, owin, openid-connect, azure-active-directory, owin-middleware

We have a web application written in ASP.NET that uses MVC for serving our Single Page Applications and Web API for ajax calls.

The authentication uses *Microsoft.Owin* and *OpenIdConnect* with Azure AD for Authority. The OAUTH flow is server side code authorization.
Then in *Startup.Auth.cs* we have

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            CookieName = CookieName,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
        };
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                   AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        /*exchange authorization code for a token 
                        stored on database to access API registered on AzureAD (using ADAL.NET) */
                    },

                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context) =>
                    {
                        /* Set the redirects URI here*/
                    },
            });
    }
```

When clicking on signin we navigate to an url whose routes map to the methods of the following MVC controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public void SignIn(string signalrRef)
    {
        var authenticationProperties = /* Proper auth properties, redirect etc.*/
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
            .Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }

    public void SignOut(string signalrRef)
    {
       var authenticationProperties = /* Proper auth properties, redirect etc.*/
       HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(authenticationProperties,
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
```

Then the end-user connected to our application is authenticated between our client apps and the ASP.net server using an ASP.NET cookie. **We would like to use Token Based approach instead**. If you are interested [this is the reason](https://github.com/Keluro/Office365-AddinWeb-SignInSample/issues/3).

I tried to replace 
the Nuget package *Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies*  by *Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth* and in Startup.cs
replacing

`app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);` by `app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());`

and in my *AccountController* we changed the challenge from `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(authenticationProperties,
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);` to `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(authenticationProperties,
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);`

The problem is that with Cookie the *set-cookie* was automatically sent in web request respond when the flow completes while redirecting to the url we specified.
**Where can I find the Bearer generated by OWIN with UseOAuthBearerAuthentication (if there is any) **, **Where and When should I send it back to my client SPAs**

**Note:** an open source sample of what we are trying to do can be found in [this github repository](https://github.com/Keluro/Office365-AddinWeb-SignInSample).

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two approaches for you to consider.

1. Use javascript libraries to perform sign-in & token acquisition within your single page app.  Then your backend is purely an web API, and can just use OAuth bearer middleware to authenticate requests.  The backend doesn't know anything about signing the user in.  We have a good sample that takes this approach [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi).  If your backend needs to make API calls as well, you could consider the OnBehalfOf flow as well.  I usually recommend this approach.
2. Use the OpenIDConnect middleware in your server to perform user sign-in and token acquisition.  You might even be able to omit the usage of the `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` entirely (although I'm not 100% sure).  You can capture the token in the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` notification as you mention, and you could redirect back to your SPA with the token in the fragment of the URL.  You could also have some route which delivers the tokens (which are cached on your server) down to your javascript.  In either case, you'll need to ensure that an outside caller can't get access to your tokens.

The thing to keep in mind will be how you refresh tokens when they expire.  If you use #1, most of it will be handled for you by libraries.  If you use #2, you'll have to manage it more yourself.

Comment: Vittorio also has a good article that would help you with #2: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/28/use-owin-azure-ad-to-secure-both-mvc-ux-and-web-api-in-the-same-project/

Comment: thx! Unless I am mistaken. Opt1, with 100% implicit flow is not adapted. We have a lot of server logic to 'join' the third party api requests (office 365 graph etc.) with our logic and we also have deamons. It seems that OnBehalfOf is what we need but it is still not supported by Azure ADv2.0 and we are trying to move to v2.0 right now... In Opt2, you are suggesting me to reuse the same JWT that was emitted between AzureAD and my server to authorize between my clients and my server, right? Actually I was hoping that a library could just make ASP.NET emit a token instead of a plain old cookie.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes no OBO for v2 yet, sorry. You are correct in your description of #2.  Your suggestion is also a good one too... Instead of using the AAD token to authorize interaction b/w client and server, you use the AAD token to initialize your own type of token, and use that instead. There are several open source libraries out there that help you generate JWTs, you could use one of those. #2 just saves you from having to do so, including the crypto and key mgmt that comes with it.